# android how to play a music of any extension from an url through MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I have an app where I want to play a music from an url. Means in edittext which music url i will give it will play by click on a button.

I am trying to using ,

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://sixpackedgeek.com/leech/files/alive.mp3");
```

but shows exception as below,

```
**07-18 14:11:21.711: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-18 14:11:21.711: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.IllegalStateException

07-18 14:11:21.711: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
**
```

What should i use here so that every extension of media file will play?
Thank you

Comment: Are you missing the prepare call before trying to play it?

Comment: no i m using prepare() before start

Comment: Are you by any chance, reusing the same media player instance? That might give you this problem if reset it not called, before you try to reuse it.